# Formulation of a constraint in a MIP for an element in different Sets

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, constraint-programming

I have an element *e* $\in E$ with $E$ the set containing all elements e and $e \in Y_i$ with $Y_i \subseteq E$. Each set $Y_i$ has different attributes.

$G_j$ is a set of sets and the following holds: $ Y_i\in\ G_j $ and $\cup_j G_j = E$

Example:

$e=5$ and sets $Y_2$={5,2,7}; $Y_{40}$={5,100,7}; ...; $Y_t$={300,400,2,5} are in $G_1$ so:

$ G_1=\{Y_2, Y_{40},..., Y_t\}$

1. In the end, I want to write a sum over a decision variable, that sums all variables found in the different sets for a particular element *e*.

   This should look likes this -> $\sum\limits^{G_1}_{Y_i \ni e}x_e(Y_i)$ or $\sum\limits^{G_j}_{Y_i}x_{e,Y_i} \; \forall e \in E: e \in Y_i:Y_i \in G_j$
2. I want a sum over all elements within a set $Y_i$

   This should look like this -> $\sum \limits^{Y_i}_e x_{e,Y_i} \; \forall\ Y_i \in G_j: e\in Y_i $

x is a binary decision variable.

With my knowledge, I do not see how a solver could work like this.

I could have used indices for the attributes found in the sets $Y_i$. This way I would avoid using $Y_i$ as an index. That though would probably add too many unnecessary decision variables that would be set to zero, since not for all elements exists these combinations of attributes.

Is there a way to formulate such a thing?

Comment: In your example, e seems to be contained in all Y_i's. I would assume that some Y_i does not contain this element e.
Also, can you explain a little bit more on "an additional parameter would be needed that would state whether a combination is impossible or not"?

Comment: @QianZhang e is contained in all sets within G1. Of course, there are other sets in which e is not contained, e.g. , $Y_1 = \{1,2,3\}$. $Y_1$ is though not in $G_1$

Comment: I don't exactly understand " I want to write a sum over a decision variable, that sums all variables found in the different sets." can you explain more or elaborate on your example what exactly you are counting or looking for?

Comment: What does “$x_e(Y_i)$” mean?

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke I am trying to sum all $x_e$ found in $Y_i \in G_1$ with that I mean. $x_{e}(Y_{2}) + x_{e}(Y_{40}) + ... + x_{e}(Y_{t})$. I do not want to use the different sets as an index, since this way I will get for some combination zero variables.

Comment: @MarcusRitt with  $x_{e}(Y_{i})$ I mean for element e found in the set $Y_i$ decide something. So $x_{e}$ kind of "belongs" to the set $Y_i$

Comment: @Georgios and this information, which variable (I assume $x_e$ is a variable) belongs to which set, in known in advance or is this unknown?

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke Yes $x_e$ is a binary variable as stated above. I do know that element *e* belongs to the sets in group $G_1$. Another element, let us call it *b* belongs to the sets within group $G_2$ and so on. So yes, I do know that $x_e$ belongs to a set $Y_i \in G_1$, $x_b$ belongs to a set $Y_j \in G_2$...

Comment: @Georgios as I understand it, you would do it the way you don't want to do it, you *will* use the set as an index, and this is not bad, because you define the variable/set pairs **only** for those existing combinations. No need to worry about "zero valued variables", you simply don't define them. I may read your question wrong, but you seem to be on the right track already. Maybe you can give it a try an post your experience again here.

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke Do you mean setting the following: $x_{e,Y_i}$ ? Would this also work if I want to get the sum of $x_e$ and $x_b$? Suppose that I have three elements *e=5*, *b=2* are in the same set $Y_2=\{5,2,7\}$ and *c=100* in another set $Y_8=\{100,200\}$. Would the constraint look like this: $ \sum \limits^{Y_2}_a x_{a,Y_2}\; with\ a \in Y_2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:
So, for all $j$ indexing the larger set of sets, let $M_j$ be the set of indices $i$ within  $G_j$, meaning $G_j=\cup_{i\in M_j}Y_i$ (e.g., $M_1=\{2,40,\ldots,t\}$). Now define the (binary) decision variable $x_{e,i}$ (to avoid using $Y_i$). This variable only exists $\forall e\in E, i\in M_j:e\in Y_i$. You could further pre-compute $Y(e) = \{i: e\in Y_i\}$ (set of i's such that $e\in Y_i$). With the notation in place:

1. $$\sum_{i\in Y(e)}{x_{e,i}} \quad  \forall e \in E$$
2. $$\sum_{e\in Y_i}{x_{e,i}} \quad  \forall j=1,2,\ldots;i\in M_j$$

Old:

Let $g \in G_1$ be any of those sets $Y_i$ you listed, and first define the union $U_1 = \displaystyle\cup_{g\in G}{g}$. Now you are sure all elements contained in the sets of $G_1$ are there. Now, if you want to "write a sum over a decision variable, that sums all variables found in the different sets", it would be $\displaystyle\sum_{e\in U_1}x_e$.

Comment: You are definitely right for all elements. My goal is though to sum only for a particular element *e*.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your question and ended up with the following:

You want to count the number of $Y_i$ sets in each set of sets $G_j$ which include the variable $e$. If it is the right way to translate your problem, my suggestion is to define binary variables with two indices like $x_{ij}$ with the following definition:

$x_{ij}=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 & \text{if $e \in Y_i$ & $Y_i \in G_j$ }\\
                  0 & \text{if $e \notin Y_i$ || $Y_i \notin G_j$}
                \end{array}
              \right.
$

then you can easily sum over the binary variables $x_{ij}$.

Comment: @Georgios Please let me know if my understanding is not correct.

Comment: I believe that you are describing *constant* information, the set membership of a variable is a parameter, no need for variables. Apart from that, you definition exactly describes this parameter.

Comment: @OguzToragay Maybe my formulation was not clear enough. Your explanation goes to the direction I want but is not quite what I am looking for. I want to select for an element *e* all the decision variables *x* that are found in different sets $Y_i$. The decision variable does not have to be 1 the way you defined it. I think I will just have to add the set $Y_i$ as an index to the decision variable -> $x_{e,Y_i}$.

Comment: @Georgios You are right, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Marco Lübbecke, thanks for the comment and correction.